# Exercise: splitting field, showing that it splits

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

I need help with this exercise:

> Let $\alpha$ be a zero of $x^3+x^2+1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Show that $x^3+x^2+1$ splits in $\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha)$. [Hint: There are eight elements in $\mathbb{Z}_2(\alpha)$. Exhibit two or more zeros of $x^3+x^2+1$, in adition to $\alpha$.]

**My attempt:**

Since our polynomial is irreducible in our starting field, we have that a basis is $1,\alpha,\alpha^2$. Our eight elements are then $0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2,1+\alpha,1+\alpha^2,\alpha+\alpha^2,1+\alpha+\alpha^2$.

I was able to show that $f(\alpha^2)=0$, because $f(\alpha)=\alpha^6+\alpha^4+1=\alpha^6+\alpha^4+1+\alpha^7-\alpha^7=\alpha^4(\alpha^3+\alpha^2+1)+1-\alpha^7=\alpha^4(0)+1-\alpha^7=1-\alpha^7$.
Now $\alpha^7=1$, because the non-zero elements of a field, is a group under, field multiplication, where 1 acts as the group identity. Since we have 8-1 nonzero elements $\alpha^7=1$.

But now I get stuck when I try to calculate the last one. The trouble is that I need to reduce what I get to one of the possibilities: $0,1,\alpha,\alpha^2,1+\alpha,1+\alpha^2,\alpha+\alpha^2,1+\alpha+\alpha^2$.

For instance I get that $f(1+\alpha)=1+\alpha+\alpha^3$, which I do not how to reduce.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a matter of repeating the trick you already know about. If $\alpha$ is a root of $f = x^{3} + x^{2} + 1$, then also $\alpha^{2}$ is, and then also $\alpha^{4} = (\alpha^{2})^{2}$. This is, as you already know, because of the binomial in characteristic two:
$$
0 = (\alpha^{3} + \alpha^{2} + 1)^{2} = (\alpha^{2})^{3} + (\alpha^{2})^{2} +1.
$$
And of course $\alpha^{2}$ and 
$$
\alpha^{4} = \alpha \alpha^{3} = \alpha (\alpha^{2} + 1) = \alpha^{3} + \alpha = \alpha^{2} + \alpha + 1
$$
are in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[\alpha]$.

Note also that the coefficient $1$ of $x^{2}$ is the sum of the roots (it is actually *minus* the sum, but signs here do not count). So once you know the roots $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{2}$, the third one will be $1 - \alpha - \alpha^{2} = \alpha^{2} + \alpha + 1$.

Comment: ... and $\alpha^8$ and $\alpha^{16}$, but that gives you nothing new :)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, right. In an elementary fashion $x^{7} + 1 = (x+1)(x^{3} + x + 1)(x^{3} + x^{2} + 1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{2}[x]$. But OP already knows that.

Comment: Thanks, I tried calculating $f(1+\alpha+\alpha^2)$, and finally managed to show that it was zero. But you seem to say that this follow directly from the fact that $\alpha$ and $\alpha^2$ are roots, why does it follow directly you mean?

Comment: @user119615, either note that since $\alpha^{2}$ is a root, so is $(\alpha^{2})^{2}$. Or note that the sum of the roots is $1$, the coefficients of $x^{2}$, and you know already the two roots $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{2}$, so the third one will be $1 - \alpha - \alpha^{2}$.